# Generalized long wave and KdV equation

Tags: waves, gravitational-waves, non-linear-systems

I have read many papers about benjamin-bona-mahony (BBM) equation or Regularized Long Wave (RLW) equation and found that BBM equation can be derived from KdV equation. from other papers i got others equation abitu long wave,namely generalized long wave (GRLW) and modified regularized long wave (MRLW). i got some questions about all of the equation:

1. what is the reason to change 
   $\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}$ with $\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^2t}$ when try to derive BBM equation from KdV equation?
2. how does it get GRLW equation from RLW? till now i have not got the explanation about that.
3. same like second question, how does it get MRLW equation?

thank you for the answer and explantion.
may be it can help

bbm equation: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t }+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^2t}=0$

kdv equation: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\delta^2\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}=0$

mrlw equation:$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t }+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\delta u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\mu\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^2t}=0$

Comment: Can you write out your initalisms?  For instance, I know what KdV stands for, but some people may not.  I do not know what BBM stands for, however.

Comment: There are several forms of the KdV equation.  Can you define $\delta$ here?  Also, in your MRLW equation, is $\delta u$ one variable or is it $\delta$ times $u$?  In that same equation, what does $\mu$ represent?